# Changing column values based on previous rows values in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that looks like this

| Name | Order |
| --- | --- |
| Manufacturer | 0 |
| Company1 | 1 |
| product | 2 |
| Company2 | 1 |
| product | 2 |
| product | 2 |
| product | 2 |

the only identifier for the value in the Names column is the order, where 0 represents Manufacturers, 1 represents companies, and 2 represents products.

And I want to add a column with a value-based in comparison between previous and current rows under the same group.

basically, I want to identify that company1 relates to Manufacturer1, and product1 relates to company1, etc...

| Name | Order | Desired_Output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Manufacturer | 0 | Manufacturer |
| Company1 | 1 | Manufacturer_Company1 |
| product | 2 | Company1_product |
| Company2 | 1 | Manufacturer_Company2 |
| product | 2 | Company2_product |
| product | 2 | Company2_product |
| product | 2 | Company2_product |

Comment: can you have two manufacturers? how you handle that?

Comment: yes the Manufacturer will have 0 in order and again the same loop would happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `pivot` the data, `ffill` and join the last two items:

```
df['output'] = (df
 .reset_index()
 .pivot(index='index', columns='Order', values='Name')
 .ffill()
 .apply(lambda d: '_'.join(d.dropna().iloc[-2:]), axis=1)
)
```

*NB. This should work with any number of 0 values.*

output:

```
           Name  Order                 output
0  Manufacturer      0           Manufacturer
1      Company1      1  Manufacturer_Company1
2       product      2       Company1_product
3      Company2      1       Company2_product
4       product      2       Company2_product
5       product      2       Company2_product
6       product      2       Company2_product
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is a little tricky but will do the job

```
df['output'] = df.apply(lambda x: df[df['Order'] == x['Order'] -1]['Name'].iloc[-1]+'_'+x['Name'] if x['Order'] > 0 else x['Name'],axis=1)
```

However, that's not the most clever solution for large dfs